# using CryptoJS with hex-string

Tags: typescript, authentication, hex, aes, cryptojs

I want to connect to a bluetooth device. Communication is via Hex-Strings only. I need to encode a 16 byte value. As a result I also expect a 16 byte value. In my implementation CryptoJS always returns a longer result. According to the documentation the IV is not needed. ("All the 16-byte data must be encrypted with the Customer Master Key currently stored in the device, using AES128 CBC
cipher mode") Therefore I set the IV to 00000000000000000000000000000000 because CryptoJS seems to require it. What am I doing wrong?

```
const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');
const value =  CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('5ff58680541c5a5903f4833dfaa4281f');
const key  = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('41435231323535552d4a312041757458'); // known master key
const ivvar   = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('00000000000000000000000000000000');
const encryptedString = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(value, key, {iv: ivvar, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding}).toString();
```

// current result is edijc9R7sl3zwZVrBBBrFQ==

Sure, the result is only a string, but it is too long anyway.

Comment: The ciphertext is Base64 encoded and is 16 bytes long after decoding: `79d8a373d47bb25df3c1956b04106b15`, e.g. [here](https://cryptii.com/pipes/base64-to-hex). Instead of a Base64 encoding you can also directly use a hexadecimal encoding. To do so, you just have to replace `toString()` with `ciphertext.toString()`, e.g. [here](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-cipher-output).

Comment: Note: Different IVs produce different ciphertexts, if the device uses a different IV than a `0`-IV, the connection is likely to fail (but since according to the description no IV is needed, a `0`-IV is plausible). By the way, for a 1 block (16 bytes for AES) plaintext, CBC with a `0`-IV is identical to ECB, so an implementation without IV would also be possible: `CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(value, key, {mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB, padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding}).ciphertext.toString();`

Comment: @Topaco: Thanks a lot, this already helped and works for the encryption. But now I am stuck with the decryption.
`const value =  CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('79d8a373d47bb25df3c1956b04106b15');
 const key  = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('41435231323535552d4a312041757458');
 const decryptedStringHex = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(value, key, { mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB, padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding});`
 decryptedStringHex is empty, seems we give the wrong input. Help appreciated.

Comment: In `decrypt`, `value` must be replaced by `{ciphertext: value}`. The hexadecimally encoded plaintext is then contained in `decryptedStringHex.toString()`.

Comment: Awesome, works as well. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the sake of completeness I would like to add the solution, which works for me. (Thanks to @Topaco)

```
encrypt(valueStringHex, keyStringHex) {
    const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');
    const value =  CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(valueStringHex);
    const key  = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(keyStringHex);
    const ivvar   = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('00000000000000000000000000000000');
    const encryptedStringHex = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(value, key, {iv: ivvar, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding}).ciphertext.toString();
    return encryptedStringHex;
    }

// encrypt('5ff58680541c5a5903f4833dfaa4281f', '41435231323535552d4a312041757458')
// returns 79d8a373d47bb25df3c1956b04106b15
```

```
decrypt(valueStringHex, keyStringHex) {
    const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');
    const value = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(valueStringHex);
    const key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(keyStringHex);
    const ivvar   = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('00000000000000000000000000000000');
    const decryptedStringHex = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt({ciphertext: value}, key, {iv: ivvar, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding});
    return decryptedStringHex.toString();
    }

// decrypt('79d8a373d47bb25df3c1956b04106b15', '41435231323535552d4a312041757458')
// returns 5ff58680541c5a5903f4833dfaa4281f
```