# How to properly encode strings so to decrypt with CryptoJs in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, encryption, encoding, character-encoding, cryptojs

I am working out a custom hybrid encryption system. I've got symmetric encryption & asymmetric encryption & decryption all handled server-side. All I need to work out now is symmetric decryption.

I got some trouble because my client is sending symmetric key, iv & data all in string format (after asymmetric decryption), but CryptoJS is very touchy with it's encoding. It's also very confusing and vague as far as documentation goes- at least for a relatively new developer. I just can't figure out what encoding CryptoJS wants for each argument. I figure I should have guessed right by now, but no.

[Docs](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/)
[Some help I've gotten previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70819452/trouble-using-cryptojs-parsing-from-decrypted-format-to-string-with-most-padding)

I'm requesting help getting the encoding right so that I can decrypt with the following. And thanks a lot for any assistance.

Example of data after asymmetric decryption as per below (throw away keys):

```
symmetricKey: bDKJVr5wFtQZaPrs4ZoMkP2RjtaYpXo5HHKbzrNELs8=,
symmetricNonce: Z8q66bFkbEqQiVbrUrts+A==,
dataToReceive: "hX/BFO7b+6eYV1zt3+hu3o5g61PFB4V3myyU8tI3W7I="
```

```
exports.transportSecurityDecryption = async function mmTransportSecurityDecryption(dataToReceive, keys) {
  const JSEncrypt = require('node-jsencrypt');
  const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");

  // Asymmetrically decrypt symmetric cypher data with server private key
  const privateKeyQuery = new Parse.Query("ServerPrivateKey");
  const keyQueryResult = await privateKeyQuery.find({useMasterKey: true});
  const object = keyQueryResult[0];
  const serverPrivateKey = object.get("key");
  const crypt = new JSEncrypt();
  crypt.setPrivateKey(serverPrivateKey);
  let decryptedDataString = crypt.decrypt(keys);
  let decryptedData = JSON.parse(decryptedDataString);

  // Symmetrically decrypt transit data
  let symmetricKey = decryptedData.symmetricKey;
  let symmetricNonce = decryptedData.symmetricNonce;
                                                        // Works perfectly till here <---
  var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
    CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(dataToReceive),
    CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(symmetricKey),
    {iv: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(symmetricNonce)}
    );
  return decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You are using the wrong encoders for data, key and IV. All three are Base64 encoded (and not hex or Utf8). So apply the Base64 encoder.
- The ciphertext must be passed to `CryptoJS.AES.decrypt()` as a `CipherParams` object or alternatively Base64 encoded, which is implicitly converted to a `CipherParams` object.

When both are fixed, the plain text is: `"[\"001\",\"001\"]"`.

```js
var symmetricKey =  "bDKJVr5wFtQZaPrs4ZoMkP2RjtaYpXo5HHKbzrNELs8="
var symmetricNonce = "Z8q66bFkbEqQiVbrUrts+A=="
var dataToReceive = "hX/BFO7b+6eYV1zt3+hu3o5g61PFB4V3myyU8tI3W7I="

var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
    dataToReceive, // pass Base64 encoded
    //{ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(dataToReceive)}, // pass as CipherParams object, works also
    CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(symmetricKey),
    {iv: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(symmetricNonce)}
);

console.log(decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you again Topaco! May I ask how you know these encoding parameters? Is it just experience working with the package or have I missed the data in the docs?

Comment: @RobbB - The documentation does mention this though, e.g. in the sections [_Encoders_](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#encoders) and [_The Cipher Input_](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-cipher-input), but rather poorly, at least not very detailed.